# Check if type is defined

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, incomplete-type

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class, class = void>
struct is_defined : std::false_type
{ };

template <class T>
struct is_defined<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_object<T>::value &&
                    !std::is_pointer<T>::value
        >
    > : std::true_type
{
private:
    static const T test; //try to create incomplete type member
};

struct defined { };

struct forward_declared;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << is_defined<defined>::value << std::endl
              << is_defined<forward_declared>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output is `true` for both. I thought if I try to make `struct` member of incomplete type, then this template specialization would be discarded from overload set. But it isn't. Removal of `static const` causes incomplete-type compile-time error. What is wrong with this approach, and if it's possible, how could this be implemented?

Comment: `is_object` doesn't mean `is_complete`.

Comment: @n.m. That is just to dissallow checking references. I could use `std::is_reference` instead, but that wouldn't make it much different.

Comment: Ah OK I see you are trying to declare a static something to weed out incomplete types. No workey either, you would need to ODR-use that static something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <class T>
struct is_defined<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_object<T>::value &&
                    !std::is_pointer<T>::value &&
                    (sizeof(T) > 0)
        >
    > : std::true_type
{
};
```

Comment: Wow that was fast :) Could you explain why we can discard the overload by trying to apply `sizeof` on incomplete type, but we can't do that by making `T` a member?

Comment: @BlackMoses It's just your run-of-the-mill SFINAE. `sizeof` is not applicable to incomplete types, so the substitution will fail.

Comment: **WARNING: THIS CODE IS WRONG.** It only tells you if the type was defined *when `is_defined` was first instantiated*. The result is cached by the compiler, and will keep its value *even after you've defined the type*. Do not use this unless for some reason you want that behavior! [Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jqjbx6n33)

Answer (score 5):

In general, in this case you can use for your sfinae expression some of those operators that don't accept incomplete types.
As an example you can use `typeid`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_defined = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_defined<T, decltype(typeid(T), void())> = true;

struct defined { };
struct forward_declared;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << is_defined<defined> << std::endl
              << is_defined<forward_declared> << std::endl;
}
```

As mentioned by others, another *valid* operator is `sizeof`.

Comment: **WARNING: THIS CODE IS WRONG.** It only tells you if the type was defined *when `is_defined` was first instantiated*. The result is cached by the compiler, and will keep its value *even after you've defined the type*. Do not use this unless for some reason you want that behavior! [Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T8ez75sME)

Answer (score 4):

As @user541686 correctly pointed out, the other solutions don't work as you most likely expect.

I managed to get the following to work (requires c++20).

```cpp
// We need this function to be evaluated each time it is called,
// since the type can become complete later in the compilation.
// We add a default argument with a lambda, which always evaluates
// to a unique type, so that the function is re-evaluated each time
template<typename T, typename G = decltype([](){})>
consteval bool is_type_complete() {
    return requires { typename std::void_t<decltype(sizeof(T))>; };
}
```

See it working: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rWq5hEYYY

This was inspired from reading https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190710-00/?p=102678

Comment: The template head of `is_type_complete` can be simplified to `template<typename T, auto = []{}>`. Also, this approach is not that *transitive* friendly. By inheriting from *essentially* a `std::integral_constant`, it allows for an easy extention of your own type trait (by in turn inheriting from it too). So I suggest to write the type trait as: `template<typename T, auto = []{}> struct is_type_complete : std::bool_constant<requires { sizeof(T); }> {};`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question "What is wrong with this approach..."
when we have static const T test; it is not a part of is_defined<...> class and we actually have to define static member is_defined<...>::test somewhere else, and only in that "else" place we need T to be complete type.
is_defined<...> class compiles just because static member size has no effect on is_defined<...> size.

Removal of static const causes T test; to be a member of is_defined<...> (and to to affect is_defined<...> size) thus T must be complete type to have known size.

**Upd note:** In case of declaring class member in template specialization it is not discarded by SFINAE just because this is nor "parameter substitution", nor kind of "SFINAE expression" (and also not a function to be overloaded!). Instead it is some kind of "SFINAE field declaration" - not what is stated by the standard to be "not an error" in case of substitution failure.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But why template specialization is not discarded from overload when such incomplete type is a member? It causes error instead.

Comment: In case of declaring class member in template specialization it is not discarded by SFINAE just because this is nor "parameter substitution", nor "SFINAE expression" (and also not a function to be overloaded!). Instead it is some kind of "SFINAE field declaration" - not what is stated by the standard to be "not an error" in case of substitution failure.